# Replacing old Xcode command line tool with newer Brew version

Tags: macos, homebrew, macos-high-sierra, xcode-command-line-tools

I'm trying to build a binary from source code which has a dependency on the package" `NASM 2.12.02 or later`. However, I have an earlier version already installed on my Mac via Xcode:

```
/usr/local/bin/nasm -v
    NASM version 0.98.40 (Apple Computer, Inc. build 11) compiled on May  1 2018
```

So to (attempt to) rectify this, I used Homebrew to install a much newer version of the package

```
brew info nasm
    nasm: stable 2.13.03 (bottled), HEAD
```

However, now my `PATH` is only pointed to the old NASM executable, while the new tool seems to be sitting in Homebrew's Cellar (ie. `/usr/local/Cellar/nasm/2.13.03`).

Is there a nice way of "switching" between these versions so that the system `PATH` views only the newer version and disregards the older one? So far I've thought of `rm -rf`-ing the old version and exporting the new version to my `PATH`, but that seems very destructive.

Also, I have run the command: `brew doctor` and have resolved all linker errors, but that has not seemed to help.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix this, I used the following command:

```
export PATH=/usr/local/Cellar/nasm/2.13.03/bin:$PATH
```

This modifies the `PATH` variable to point to the `/usr/local/Cellar/nasm/2.13.03/bin` directory and find the `nasm` executable there before looking in `/usr/local/bin`.